# Alert before leaving page (navigate back) with Ionic v2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How do you show an `alert`, that the user must close, before going back to the previous page? I'm using the standard `<ion-navbar *navbar>` *arrow button*.

I tried hooking into the `NavController` event `ionViewWillLeave` like this, but it doesn't work:

```
ionViewWillLeave() {
  let alert = Alert.create({
    title: 'Bye',
    subTitle: 'Now leaving',
    buttons: ['OK']
  });
  this.nav.present(alert);
}
```

This shows the alert, but doesn't go back once it is closed. If I comment it out, the back button works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As of Ionic2 RC, now we can use [Nav Guards](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#nav-guards).

> In some cases, a developer should be able to control views leaving and
>   entering. To allow for this, NavController has the ionViewCanEnter and
>   ionViewCanLeave methods. Similar to Angular 2 route guards, but are
>   more integrated with NavController

So now we can do something like this:

```
someMethod(): void {
    // ...
    this.showAlertMessage = true;
}

ionViewCanLeave() {
    if(this.showAlertMessage) {
        let alertPopup = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Exit',
            message: '¿Are you sure?',
            buttons: [{
                    text: 'Exit',
                    handler: () => {
                        alertPopup.dismiss().then(() => {
                            this.exitPage();
                        });         
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Stay',
                    handler: () => {
                        // need to do something if the user stays?
                    }
                }]
        });

        // Show the alert
        alertPopup.present();

        // Return false to avoid the page to be popped up
        return false;
    }
}

private exitPage() {
    this.showAlertMessage = false;
    this.navCtrl.pop();
}
```

I prefer to use the `this.showAlertMessage` property, so we can have more control over when we need to show the alert if the user tries to exit the page. For instance, we may have a form in the page, and if the user didn't make any changes, we don't want to show the alert (`this.showAlertMessage = false`) and if the form was actually changed, we want to show the warning (`this.showAlertMessage = true` )

---

**OLD ANSWER**

After a few hours struggling with this, I've found the solution.

One issue that I had to face is that the `ionViewWillLeave` is executed also when the `alert` is closed so that makes things more complicated (when the `view` is about to be closed because you pressed the back button, the `alert` shows up, but when you click *ok*, that fires the event again and opens the `alert` again and so on...).

Another thing to keep in mind is that `ActionSheets` and `Alerts` get added to the `navigation stack`, so `this.nav.pop()` instead of removing the current view from the stack, removes the `alert` (and because of that we may feel it's not working properly).

That being said, the solution I've found is:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams, Alert} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/mypage/mypage.html',
})
export class MyPage{

    // ....

    confirmedExit: boolean = false;

    constructor(private nav: NavController, navParams: NavParams) {
        // ...
    }

    ionViewWillLeave() {
        if(!this.confirmedExit) {
            let confirm = Alert.create({
                title: 'Bye',
                message: 'Now leaving',
                buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Ok',
                    handler: () => {
                        this.exitPage();
                    }
                }
                ]
            });
            this.nav.present(confirm);
        }
    }

    public exitPage(){
        this.confirmedExit = true;
        this.nav.remove().then(() => {
            this.nav.pop();
        });
    }


  }
```

So:

- I use a `confirmedExit` variable to know if you already clicked the ok button (so you confirmed you wanted to exit the page, and with that I know that the next time the `ionViewWillLeave` event is fired, I don't have to show the `alert`)
- In the `exitPage` method, first I do `this.nav.remove()` to remove the `alert` from the stack, and once that's done, we do the `this.nav.pop()` to go back to the previous page.

---

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just add a custom back button and hide the automatic one?

Comment: @BoštjanPišler but what if the user does not use that new button, but the android physical back button?

Comment: aaah, touché :)

Comment: I'm actually having issues getting this to work in RC3, the page navigates and then the alert shows up. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated the answer, please let me know if it helps :)

Comment: yea just posted the same as a new answer :)

Answer (score 13):

The accepted solution doesn't work in RC3, here's a new one using [Nav Controller](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/)'s Nav Guard:

```
ionViewCanLeave(): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      message: 'Bunnies will die :(',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'OK',
        handler: () => {
          resolve();
        },
      }, {
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: () => {
          reject();
        }
      }],
    });
    confirm.present();
  })
}
```

If you are navigating using push() on the nav controller, you also need to do a catch on it otherwise it will throw an unhandled error:

```
this.navCtrl.push(SomePage).catch(() => {});
```

Comment: I just tried this (RC3, latest app-scripts), but while 'OK' works, 'Cancel' throws: `.\node_modules\@angular\core\src\error_handler.js:53 Error: Uncaught (in promise): false`

Comment: You're right, in case of using push or similar a catch has to be used, I edited the answer, thanks.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @Cocowalla , implicit error handling will be added in v`2.1.0`

Comment: Using 2.1.0, change the return type to Promise<{}> or you get a type mismatch error. Other than that works a treat, cheers!

Comment: Thank you, this is an accepted answer. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

this is my version of **Bostjan** answer, without throwing unhandled exception.

```
ionViewCanLeave(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (!this.formGroup.dirty) return resolve(true);

        this._alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Confirm leaving',
            message: 'There is unsave work, do you like to continue leaving?',
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Leave',
                handler: () => {
                    resolve(true);
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Stay',
                handler: () => {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            }]
        }).present();
    });
}
```